# Would using a template for a Privacy Policy be considered as duplicate content?

Tags: duplicate-content, privacy-policy

I have to write the Privacy Policy for a website.  I am thinking of using something along the lines of a template I found [here](http://default-template.wikidot.com/legal:privacy-policy) on `wiki.dot`.

If I use this template, and insert our company name, will this be considered 'duplicate content' because I'm thinking others have use this as well?

Comment: See this video by Matt Cutts from Google on this: [How does required duplicate content (terms and conditions, etc.) affect search?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi-wkEeOKxM). John is correct about blocking it from crawlers if you're concerned about it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, yes. However, it is only one page so by itself it won't hurt you. If you have lots of pages with duplicate/low quality content this just makes it worse by adding another page to the mix.

You can always block that page from being crawled and indexed with robots.txt and `x-robots.tag` to prevent Google from considering that page in its algorithm or make it a canonical URL of that template you linked to. Both would solve this problem.